# RestAngular multiple scopes created top scopes populated others null

Tags: angularjs, restangular

**This is the code that I am using...**

```
var Agencyapp = angular.module('MainPage', ['restangular']);


angular.module('MainPage').controller('AgenciesCtrl', function ($scope, Restangular) {

Restangular.setBaseUrl('http://localhost/MappingServicesWebAPI/api');
$scope.Agencies = Restangular.all("mapping").get();



});
```

I am simple trying to return a list of agencID's and AgencyNames. 
The Url is correct and when I paste it into Chrome it returns the correct data but I am getting the error "Unable to get property 'toString' of undefined or null reference"

Not sure what I am doing wrong...

I've changed my code to this...

```
var Agencyapp = angular.module('MainPage', ['restangular']);


angular.module('MainPage').controller('AgenciesCtrl',['$scope','Restangular', function       ($scope, Restangular) {

Restangular.setBaseUrl('http://localhost/MappingServicesWebAPI/api');
Restangular.all('mapping');
var baseAccounts = Restangular.all('mapping');
baseAccounts.getList().then(function(gotAgencies){
    var _Agencies = gotAgencies[0];
    $scope.Agencies = _Agencies.getList('mapping');
});


}]);
```

Now i see multiple scopes the top 2 populated and the rest of the null,
why would this be?

**This is what the Scopes look like in chrome...**

```
< Scope (002)
    < Scope (003)
     < Scope (006)
     < Scope (007)
     < Scope (008)
     < Scope (009)
     < Scope (00A)
     < Scope (00B)
     < Scope (00C)
     < Scope (00D)
     < Scope (00E)
     < Scope (00F)
     < Scope (00G)
     < Scope (00H)
     < Scope (00I)
     < Scope (00J)
     < Scope (00K)
     < Scope (00L)
     < Scope (00M)
     < Scope (00N)
     < Scope (00O)
     < Scope (00P)
     < Scope (00Q)
     < Scope (00R)
     < Scope (00S)
     < Scope (00T)
     < Scope (00V)
     < Scope (00W)
     < Scope (00X)
     < Scope (00Y)
     < Scope (00Z)
     < Scope (010)
     < Scope (011)
     < Scope (012)
     < Scope (004)
```

Scope 006 and 007 are populated with data the rest are null

Comment: Hey,

In the first example you're using get to get a list of elements, so that's what's wrong. The rest, I don't know exactly what you want to fetch, but the first case would do a GET to: `http://localhost/MappingServicesWebAPI/api/mapping`, I don't know if that's the idea. But Restangular doesn't create any scopes, so I don't know what's going on

Comment: Does the way i changed the code look right?  Do you have any troubleshooting tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problems were caused by using a JavaScript library called **Slidebox.js**

Once I either removed the AngularJS code from the containing  or commented out the include to Slidebox.js everything worked great.